# КриптоПро не работает подпись на Linux

Tags: linux, криптография, криптопро

Получил сертификат, добавил его в установленный КриптоПро на Linux. Но при попытке подписать документ получаю ошибку. Может кто-нибудь объяснить, что не хватает и где получить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сертификат используется для проверки электронной подписи. Для подписи нужны приватный ключ и сертификат. Обычно приватный ключ записан на токене. Подключи токен к компьютеру (и установи драйвера если требуется) и должно сработать.

Из некоторых токенов приватный ключ можно достать и перезаписать на виртуальный (называется диск или реестр).

Сертификат в каком виде выдали? посмотри что есть в транспортном файле. Попробуй импортировать ключик в HDIMAGE. В гуях `показать расширенные` - `сертификаты` - `импортировать ключи`.

Comment: У меня нет токена. Для нас выпустили только сертификат. Пойду к Тинькофф спрошу как мне делать подписи раз нет приватного ключа.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов добавил строчку в ответ

Comment: Мне подсказали как найти. Управление сертификатами (набрал Сертификаты в поиске) и выполнил экспорт установленного сертификата и закрытого ключа в pfx. А потом этот pfx установил там, где мне нужно.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов вот там его надо кспортировать вмесле с ключом и импортировать на линукс через импорт ключа.